# Catch all remaining redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am replacing a site and I am creating page specific redirects followed by a directory redirect for any pages in a section I may have missed.

Is there a way to add at the end a catch all so any page that doesn't have a specific redirect or resides outside a directory it still redirects to the new home page.

Example of the set up I have in place:

```
# Page specific redirects
Redirect 301 /about/page-1 http://newsite.com/about/page-1
Redirect 301 /about/page-2 http://newsite.com/about/page-2

# Wildcard redirect for any remaining pages in this section
RedirectMatch 301 ^/about/.*$ http://newsite.com/about
```

If there are singular pages that are not in the "About" section of the site is there a way I can create a wildcard that catches all and redirects to the home page?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redirect all pages / directories to new site, you can use regex. You should read [RedirectMatch Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch).

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/.*)$ http://newsite.com$1
```

Comment: I don't want to use a general redirect for all pages to go to the home page of the new site. What I'm trying to do is match up pages from the old site to similar pages in the new site. So for example if a user has an /about-us page bookmarked then they will go to the similar /about-us page on the new site. This is also to help with search engines.

I have all the individual pages mapped but I know there will be some odd pages missed. I was wondering if there is a catch all expression that will allow for any other pages that aren't already mapped to go to the home page on the new site?

Comment: what are the rules to redirect? just a list of mapping or any conditions met?